# how do i send two messages in one?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i am making a command where when you type `,link` or `,l` it gives a message and the link to put my bot in your server, but there is a delay between both messages so someone can talk between both the messages, how could i send both messages without any delay.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'link',
    aliases: ["l"],
    description: '[DESCRIPTION]',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        message.channel.send(`Here is the link to add this bot in your server, hope to see you there!`);
        message.channel.send(`https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=828796185404768266&scope=bot&permissions=8589934591`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Send it as a single message? Use `\n` for new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could Use `\n` To Make a New Line

or

You Can Use this code to make the text a link

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  embed.setTitle("BOT INVITE LINK")
  embed.setColor("BLACK")
  embed.setURL("INVITE LINK")
  embed.setDescription("**Click On The Blue Title Above to Invite BOT to Your Server :D**")
  
  message.channel.send(embed)
```